# How to trace a npm module in AWS Lambda?

Tags: nestjs

I have deployed the NestJS app to AWS Lambda, and there's an error message :

```
Cannot find module 'hbs'
```

PS :

- Module `hbs` has been installed locally using `npm install hbs --save`
- it's running well in my local

is there anyone who knows how to trace this issue in AWS Lambda? My feeling tells me that I have to trace this module in AWS Lambda, to make sure it's uploaded, but I don't know how to trace it.

Answer (score 0):

You either have your lambda in and it's `node_modules` in `s3` or you have your lambda deployed on a container using `ECR` , if it's the first case make sure you have the module in your node_module directory and if it's the second case make sure that you have your package in `package.json` and `npm install` in your `Dockerfile`.